# Cobination of mvc 4,entity framework, stored procedures is the right way?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures

We are doing a new project, for all devices and browsers compatibility we have decided to use asp.net mvc 4, Html5, css 3, for communicating with Database Entity Framework we want to use.

Our senior members(Manager, DBA(they are also new to mvc 4, EF)) in the team asking us to write every thing will be in the stored procedures while communicating Database so that maintenance becomes easy.

Is it the correct match if we go like that(MVC4+ EF + stored procedures)? Will i not get maintenance and performance if i go with Code first reverse engineering(because database tables are ready i want to do like that),  Please reply.

Below is the flow we want to do, please correct me

1. As Database is already ready, so first we will write the stored procedures for communication with DB.
2. New Mvc 4 project and will add .edmx file(EF) and select tables and Stored procedures
3. in mvc controller or web api we write the consuming stored procedures

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing *technically* wrong with ASP.NET MVC + EF + Stored Procedures approach, from the first sight.

But my experience show, is that typically it's huge overkill. The common problem I see is the **conflicting** interests between developers and DBA's. In most worst scenarios all DB releated stuff are controlled by DBA, so if developer what to add/change some feature he needs to wait for implementation of it by DBA (or wait for approve, which could also take long).

So, I personally see that as more *bureaucratic* way of development.

My own perpective is to be more agile on development and tools like Code First matches that. Stored Procedures could still play major role, while code/performance optimization, but not something to start with.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that using stored procedures in the database is a good approach.  Centralizing data validation and calculations in the database ensures data integrity.  Client-side validation is important for the user experience but you must also ensure that you test the data validity in the database.
Using Entity Framework, you can generate entities which relate directly to tables in your database, or else you can design entities which use procedures for insert/update/delete operations rather than simple table updates.
In MVC you will use the entities as models to manage your data interactions.
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

This is my personal view. I am sure others might have different ones. Since you are asking this question I am hoping you are open for discussions, otherwise I wouldn’t have bothered as this topic is like a religious discussion as lots of people have very strong opinions and are not likely to change them.

Personally I don't think stored procedures are meant to write business logic. They should be used for writing data access logic. I would only use a stored procedure if I want to optimize an expensive query such as a dynamic search but nothing else. You will get slightly less performance if you have your logic in the domain model, but its not even noticeable in most situations.

One of the strong arguments for writing business logic in stored procedures is because you can easily change some logic by changing your stored procedure. But should we really go and change the business logic of a deployed application without doing proper testing. What will happen if you accidently do a mistake?  Doing a deployment is not such a big deal now with continuous builds and I don’t think as a professional developer you should take that risk.

When you decide to write your logic in stored procedures, you give up all the object oriented concepts and you end up writing some procedural code that we wrote maybe 10 years ago. C# language has come a long way now and you will not be able to use those new language features in heart of your application which is business logic. You also loose the visual studio features to refactor code, advanced and easy debugging features etc.

I also don’t like the idea of having triggers as it’s not visible in source code. Imagine someone new in your team trying to add a new feature some time later and if he doesn’t know that a trigger exists, he might write some incorrect logic.

If your application contains some complex business logic, (I am sure most applications do) you should have a domain model that contains not only just properties of your entities, but also your logic. Otherwise you will be falling in to the anti-pattern called anemic data model.

You will not be able to test your business logic by writing unit testing if you have your logic in stored procedures.

You will also not be able to deploy your business logic to multiple servers if you have them in stored procedures if your site becomes really successful.

You will also not be using all powerful capabilities of Entity framework and LINQ if you have all your logic in your stored procedures. You actually don’t need an ORM Mapper if that is the approach you are going to take.

This is what I would recommend for your project.
Even though you already have the database, you can still use code first approach of Entity framework.  You can download the EF code first reverse engineer power tool and have the code first code auto generated for you. This is going to be a one off thing and after than if you have any more changes, you can directly do to the database and update the code first code accordingly. Fluent API is bit confusing at first, but you can easily learn that from the generated code.

Do not access your data context from the controller. Have a repository layer that will contain all your data access logic. You can access the repository from your controller. (This allows you to unit test your code by mocking the repository). There are lots of video tutorials on how to use the repository pattern on asp.net site.

Your domain model is going to be the entities that got generated from the Entity framework. Try to have your business logic in those models.  It takes a little while to get use to the domain model pattern. But one you get used to it you will start to appreciate its benefits.

Hope this helps.

Comment: One big advantage to using stored procedures would be that if the webserver was compromised, an attacker would not be able to extract the user-table (if only EXEC permission was given and the database service is not running on the webserver). I am personally looking to use SP for account control with MVC4 SPA.